# How can I shortened this?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, while-loop

I am trying to self teach myself programming and started with javascript. To learn more I have been completing challenges to practice and one challenge was to write a script that would determine the first case of the word in a string with the most repeated letters. I was able to complete it with this code I made:

```js
string = "Hey i believe";
string = string.split(" ");
stringarray = [];
longestlength = 0; 

for (i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
    stringarray.push(0);
}

for (i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
    if (string[i].length > longestlength) {
        longestlength = string[i].length;
        longestword = string[i];
    }
}

for (x = 0; x < string.length; x++) {
    y = 0;
    z = 0;
    while (z < string[x].length) {
        if (string[x].substr(z,1) == string[x].substr(y,1) && z !== y) {
            stringarray[x] += 1;
            y = string[x].length -1;
        }
        y++;
        if (y == string[x].length) {
            z++;
            y = z;
        }
    }
}

if (Math.max.apply(null,stringarray) === 0) {
    mostrptltword = -1;
}
else {
    mostrptltword = string[stringarray.indexOf(Math.max.apply(null,stringarray))];
}

console.log(mostrptltword);
```

But to get all the points possible for the challenge it must be completed in less than 10 minutes this took me 25 mins. So my question is am I over complicating things; causing me to write a much longer script than needed? I have read a little bit about things like Regular Expressions and how they can really shortened script lengths and the time it takes to write them would that or maybe another technique of been more useful than all the loops I had to make?

Comment: If the code is working fine as is, and you're just looking for ways to write this more cleanly, this should probably be moved to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Considering that you never actually use the final values of `longestlength` and `longestword`, you can get rid of that loop and those variables.

Comment: what is meant by "most repeated letters" anyhow, I could interpret that 10 ways from Sunday.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var words = "Heyyyyy I believe".split(' '); // split the words into an array


var values = [],   // total of times that a letter appears
    k = 0,         // 'global' counter. I'm using this to iterate over the values array
    heigher = 0,   // holds de heigher occurrence of a letter 
    letter = "";   // the letter that most appears in that word
    word = "";     // the word


// iterate over all the words
for(var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {  

    // iterate over each letter in each word
    for(var j = 0; j < words[i].length; j++) {

        // holds the occurrence time
        // RegEx: get the word in the position 'i' and check how many times the letter appears on the position [j] appears
        values[k] = words[i].match(new RegExp(words[i][j],'g')).length;

        // check if the next letter appears more times than the previous one
        if(values[k] > heigher) {
            // hold the values of interest
            heigher = values[k];
            letter = words[i][j];
            word = words[i];
        }
        k++;
    } 
}

console.log("word: " + word + " letter: " + letter + " total: " + heigher);
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/felipemiosso/FyCHG/

The is commented. Hope it helps :)

Comment: Oh wow, that sure helped a lot! And it gave me a better understanding of how useful RegExp can be.